# Dealing with end of 'file' using BufferedReader.read()

Tags: java, sockets

I have a client server program which MUST send a file's content as a String and am having trouble deciding how to end the while loop containing the BufferedReader.read method.I have the code as:

```
while((c = in.read()) != -1){                             
    fw.write((char)c);
    System.out.print((char)c);
}
```

But as it uses sockets, it never reaches -1 until the socket is closed. I cant figure out an ending clause for the while loop to reach. Are there any special characters?

Went with:

```
while((line = in.readLine()) != null && !line.equals(BasicProtocol.SENDING_FILE_DONE))
```

where SENDING_FILE_DONE is a String which is added to the end of the stream. Not a good way of doing it but has to be this way (I believe) when the data must be a String.

Comment: I haven't done this so I'm not sure, why not write -1 when the end of file is reached while writing to the socket?

Comment: Did you try in.readLine(), if it works then you only need to check for null?

Comment: @Thihara Doesnt work im afraid

Comment: @Thihara You *can't* write -1, you can only write a byte, and even if you could it wouldn't cause read() to return -1. That happens because of an out-of-band EOS indication: in the case of a TCP socket, a FIN flag in the segment. @ Titus this is not a good point at all.

Comment: @EJP byte value of `0xFF` is -1.  Just saying.

Comment: @Legend Exactly. You write the byte 0xff. Neither that value nor any other byte value will cause `read()` to return -1.

Comment: @EJP I see the light now... No wait is that a -1? Oh shit EOF...

Answer (score 1):

> I have a client server program which MUST send a file's content as a String

Why? Bad idea. It should be sent as bytes. Otherwise you are running the risk of data corruption.

> and am having trouble deciding how to end the while loop containing the `BufferedReader.read()` method

1. You shouldn't be using a `BufferedReader` at all, you should be using a `BufferedInputStream`, to avoid the assumption that the file contains text.
2. You should have sent the file size ahead of the file, and you should read the file size, then loop until you have read exactly that many bytes, OR You should close the socket after sending the file.

Comment: Yeah but it's a stupid assignment with that specification unfortunately. It's botchy but I've actually gone with the readline method because its easier to append some text at the end, still - very poor design but not by choice.

Comment: So you got it working using readLine() ? Can you please post the changes ?

Comment: I got it working but in a sub-par manner. I.e I could've done the same with read() but one specified EOF character is more likely to occur than a string so it will just 'have to do'.

Comment: @Titus What if the data contains a newline? `readLine()` is simply not a solution.

Comment: @EJP I believe it will read as "" and then when a println() is called a blank line will be inserted.

Comment: @Titus Wrong on both counts. It will be thrown away by `readLine()`, and replaced in `println()` by whatever the platform's line terminator is, which might be different. Another thing: what if the file already contains your magic constant `BasicProtocol.SENDING_FILE_DONE`? Believe me this is not a solution. If it is an assignment you will fail, and you will be given the same reasons I am giving you here if you ask why. If it is real work you will have to fix it some time. Get it right now.

Comment: @EJP I definitely understand that if my magic constant is already in the file the program will not work but I can't see any other way of doing it. My professor has already admitted that he should've told us to use ByteStreams but 'he isn't a java programmer so didn't know they existed' is what he said. Truly, if you could give me a better solution I will certainly implement it. :)

Comment: I've given you one. Just close the socket after you send the file. Then you have your EOS condition, and your original code will work.

Comment: @EJP I can't close the socket as the client has to be persistent. :o

Comment: @Titus In that case you can tell your professor from me that he has set an insoluble problem. Show him this exchange.

Comment: @Thirara I wasn't confronted with the situation, and it's a long time ago, but I would expect any professional to recognize a mistake when pointed out, with a credible supporting argument, which is why I suggested the backup of showing him this exchange.

Comment: @EJP Haha cheers EJP I appreciate it. I think I'll save the confrontation for if he gives me a bad mark.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using BufferedReader, you can try reading the entire line at one go ..

```
String line;
while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
  // your code here
}
```

Comment: Will I need to append newline characters? And how do I keep them system independent?

Comment: writer.newLine(); // if you are using BufferedWriter to write.

Comment: What line? How does reading lines solve a problem with EOS? @Sudhanshu Yes you would have to append a newline, but then what if the file already contains newlines? This will not work. -1.

Comment: Can we not use BufferedReader to read from the socket? I don't see a reason why the above code won't work?

Comment: I've told you. Using `readLine()` assumes there are no internal newlines in the file. If there are, you will only get the file up to that point.

Comment: OP wants to send contents as a STRING - so the requirement is very specific.

Comment: @Sudhanshu That requirement does not exclude the possibility that the file, and therefore the String, contains a newline, and the original EOS problem remains. Not an answer.